# Git Clone imreachable. Timeout error

Tags: linux, git, putty

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the “fade” filter for FFmpeg?](https://superuser.com/questions/529670/how-do-i-install-the-fade-filter-for-ffmpeg)

I have tried to perform the following commands

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg
git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264
```

But unfortunately I am getting the following outputs:

```
"Initialized empty Git repository in ... "
"errno=Connection timed out"
"errno=Network is unreachable"
"fatal: unable to connect a socket (Network is unreachable)"
```

Is it a temporary problem?

Comment: I tried them both and they work for me. Must be something wrong with your connection. Can you resolve and ping the servers?

Comment: Btw if you're just trying to get a version with the newest filters, download a static build from the download page instead of compiling yourself. That'll save you time.

Comment: @slhck : How do i use the static build. I found it here. http://dl.dropbox.com/u/24633983/ffmpeg/index.html But i have no idea how to use it.

Comment: @Haru : I can ping the servers. I tried in my local system, they worked for me. It is not working in the server :(

Comment: I checked the log file and found that the server has been block in iptables. Now i can download those files :)

Comment: Simply extract the tarball, and run `ffmpeg` from the path where you downloaded it from. E.g. go to `~/Downloads/ffmpeg-linux64-20130109/` and then run `./ffmpeg`. If FFmpeg should be available anywhere in the shell, uninstall the `yum` version of FFmpeg and then copy the `ffmpeg` file from the archive to `/usr/bin/`.

Comment: No, just copy the single one `ffmpeg` file from the archive to `/usr/bin/`, as I said.

Comment: For others with (probably local) network issues who want the source you can alternatively download the [x264 source snapshot](ftp://ftp.videolan.org/pub/x264/snapshots/last_x264.tar.bz2) and [FFmpeg source snapshot](http://ffmpeg.org/releases/ffmpeg-snapshot.tar.bz2).

Comment: I got it. So, if there is an update, I need to replace that ffmpeg file. Please post an answer.

Comment: Well, since it's the same problem I just closed it as a duplicate of the other :)